# What do authors usually mean from a geometrical interpretation when "radially symmetric" is mentioned?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was reading up on a text on an investigated case on heat flow in an annulus. The author mentioned "radially symmetric" and consequently proceeded to deduce that the variable 'theta' can be done away with.

A simple explanation of radially symmetric and the consequences to the variable 'theta' would be helpful.

Edit:grammatical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the coordinate system used, since the radial coordinate has different meanings in different systems. In the case of the annulus, the author is probably considering a natural polar coordinate system in which any point can be defined by its distance $r$ from the origin (placed at the center of the annulus), and it's angle $\theta$ from some fixed direction (usually form the horizontal). Radial symmetry means that the value under consideration (probably temperature in this problem) depends only on the radius $r$ because the initial conditions and boundary values of the problem depend only on $r$. In cases like this, we can assume that the derivative of the quantity under consideration with respect to $\theta$ is zero, which usually simplifies the problem greatly.

Answer (score 1):

"Radially symmetric" means it has a full symmetry on rotation around some axis.  A perfect circle, or disc, is radially symmetric; as is a cylinder, cone, torus, or annulus, &c. .

The variable theta $(\theta)$ is often used to denote an angle.  In this case, likely the angle about the axis of the annulus measured from some diametric axis.

If the system is radially symmetric, then whatever is being measured (temperature gradients, heat flow, &c) is invariant with respect to that angle, and thus the angle is not a factor in calculations